# Json serialization on Flutter gives can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to serialize a simple Dart class. As you can see, I added everything related to the serialization. The name of the file is `ParamDescription.dart`.

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'ParamDescription.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class FxParamDescription {
  String name;
  double minValue;
  double maxValue;
  double defaultValue;

  FxParamDescription(){

  }

  factory FxParamDescription.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FxParamDescriptionFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FxParamDescriptionFromJson(this);
}
```

I run  `flutter pub run build_runner build` and it finishes without errors.

When trying to compile, I get this error

```
                               ^
lib/fx/ParamDescription.dart:24:65: Error: The argument type 'FxParamDescription' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
 - 'FxParamDescription' is from 'package:flutter_app/fx/ParamDescription.dart' ('lib/fx/ParamDescription.dart').
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FxParamDescriptionFromJson(this);
                                                                ^
lib/fx/ParamDescription.dart:24:36: Error: A value of type 'FxParamDescription' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
 - 'FxParamDescription' is from 'package:flutter_app/fx/ParamDescription.dart' ('lib/fx/ParamDescription.dart').
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FxParamDescriptionFromJson(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FxParamDescriptionFromJson(this);
```

To

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FxParamDescriptionToJson(this);
```

You're using the wrong generated function.